# Ribbon Menu macro fails if I save presentation with different name

Tags: vba, powerpoint, menuitem, ribbon

How do I create a Powerpoint Ribbon macro menu item without including the file (Presentation) name  reference (like I can do in Excel).
When I add a VBA macro to the Powerpoint ribbon as a menu item it includes the current presentation name with the macro name. If I save the presentation as a different name this presentation name is not updated and the menu-macro fails with message "This macro cannot be found or has been disabled because of your security settings".

Original menu-macro reference: "Eng_Viet!BackUp" where "Eng_Viet" is the pptm Presentation name and "BackUp" is the VBA subroutine (macro)

If I save the presentation as a new file eg. "Eng_Viet_Backup.pptm" then new name presentation tries to execute the original menu reference "Eng_Viet!BackUp and of course it fails.

In Excel the File name is not added to to the Menu-macro name.

Comment: PowerPoint's built-in Ribbon modification automatically includes the file name. To add a macro to the Ribbon without a file name reference, use an OOXML editor like the one on this page: https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor Here is Microsoft's introductory page to this kind of ribbon modification: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/customize-the-office-fluent-ribbon-by-using-an-open-xml-formats-file

Comment: Thank you, that solution worked. It's the first time I have viewed the ribbon as XML modifiable. You have opened another world for me.